# How do I substitute using a regex like a string template?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

So here is the scenario. I have a user defined regular expression stored in variable `my_regex`. I should have no other knowledge than it having a named group called `id`. For example, one valid regex could be:

```
my_regex = /ABC(?<id>...)ABC/
```

I'm trying to do this: match this regex against a string, and substitute the group `id` with a fixed string `'123'`. For example:

```
my_func(my_regex, 'ABC789ABCQQQQ')
#=> 'ABC123ABCQQQQ'
```

Now I know that this could be done if I got to define the regex myself, for example, I could define `my_regex` as `/(ABC)(...)(ABC)/`, and just use

```
my_match_data = my_regex.match('ABC789ABCQQQQ')
result = my_match_data.captures[0] + '123' + my_match_data.captures[2]
```

However, aside from the fact that I'm not the one who gets to define it, this solution is ugly and not generalizable. What if instead of one `id`, I have `id1`, `id2` and `id3`, with arbitrary order?

I was looking for something as elegant as a string template for regex, for example, imagine:

```
result = my_regex.match('ABC789ABCQQQQ') % {id: '123'}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I still cannot find a built-in solution for this. So here is a simple extension that achieves something close.

```
class MatchData
  def %(hash)
    string_copy = string.dup
    hash.each do |key, value|
      string_copy[self.begin(key)..self.end(key)] = value
    end
    string_copy
  end
end

my_regex = /ABC(?<id>...)ABC/
puts my_regex.match('ABC789ABCQQQQ') % {id: '123'}
```

Comment: This is actually pretty great!

Comment: @ndn: Do you mean just `string_copy` instead of `return string_copy`?

Comment: Where does `string` come from?

Comment: @sawa, [`MatchData#string`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/MatchData.html#method-i-string)

Answer (score 0):

You could do that like so:

```
regex = /1(?<cat>[a-z]+)2ABC(?<id>\d+)ABC/
str = '21dog2ABC789ABCQQQQ'
name = :id   
replacement = '123'

m = regex.match(str)
  #=> #<MatchData "1dog2ABC789ABC" cat:"dog" id:"789">
i = m.begin(name)
  #=> 9
str[0,i] + replacement + str[i+m[name].size..-1]
  #=> "21dog2ABC123ABCQQQQ"
```